# How to stop relying on dominant leg in squat?

Tags: form, muscle-imbalance

For a while I've noticed that I lean a lot on my right leg during my squats and it went on for a while.

I am currently squatting 200lbs, which is great, but lowering all the way down to 145 and I still notice that I am cheating on my right side. I took a hit to my ego dropping this low, but it is for the better and I will keep lowering my weight until I find a spot where my form is correct (95lbs is fine during warm up).

Last week, I added unilateral leg press and this made it very clear that my left leg is weaker than my right. My left glute is definitely weaker too.

What should I do to help with my form? Is unilateral workouts the way to go until I fix this imbalance and my squat form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unilateral work will assist you in making sure you train both sides equally. And do make sure you train them equally. Training one side more than the other will only lead to another set of imbalances.

That said, you should still be squatting, while being mindful of symmetry. This is of course because you still need to practice good form in order to learn good form.

Comment: Yeah, I set up 180lbs on the leg press (normally 400lbs) and started with the left, it was really hard and then with the right and it felt relatively easy. During unilateral, I should set the weight challenging for the easy side and work both legs with that weight? I am going to practice form.

Comment: The best way to ensure equal work, is to do your weak side first, and then mimic it with the other leg. Let the weak leg dictate weight/set/reps.

Answer (score 0):

You should first set the weight limit in which you feel your that both the legs are working in parallel. Once this weight becomes comfortable, you can start to add load. In this way you can manage the symmetry and balanced workout for both your legs.